# How do I setup a pppoe connection in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, pppoe, adsl

I have a bridged ADSL modem (BSNL for all those from India). I need to connect to it via my Ubuntu 12.04, but I am not able to figure out how to form that connection. I am able to connect to that router via wifi but after that I am not able to connect to the internet. How do I go about it.

Please try and provide a simple solution as I am fairly new to the Linux environment.

Comment: If the ADSL modem is bridged, then you still need to be logged in (via PPPoE or PPPoA) to connect to the Internet.

Comment: please read my comment below, I tried pppoeconf and now Ubuntu is not loading any of its network settings. I think I will have to do a fresh installations.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run /usr/sbin/pppoeconf? It has a nice user-interface and can help setup the networking. All you need is the username and password.

Comment: I did but it does not help at all. I am still not able to connect to the internet. Mind you that I have a bridged internet connection. So I first need to connect to the router and then I need to establish an pppoe internet connection. And plus I am using wifi to do all this, not a physical cable. Just want to clear the air!

Comment: Well I tried using pppoeconf but now everytime I restart my system, it says "setting network configrations" and then it does get any network configrations and it does not load any network settings. Now I am not able to connect to the internet at all, I do not see the wifi icon on my menu panel.... what has happened?